# Is there any way to allow \n in a django template? (bootstrap-popover)

Tags: python, django, twitter-bootstrap, django-templates, popover

I have this string

```
{{contact.info}}
```

The value is:

```
name teste\nteste@teste.com.br\n(11) 11111-1111\n(0) 12312-3123\n(12) 12312-3123\n
```

In html I want to see it:

```
name teste
teste@teste.com.br<br>
(11) 11111-1111
(10) 12312-3123
(12) 12312-3123
```

Have any way?

Comment: The issue isn't the template, it's that a newline in HTML doesn't do anything...

Comment: Have any way to do it?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Use the [`autoescape` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#autoescape) to escape HTML linebreak (`<br />`) characters.

In addition, since you do not have html linebreak characters, you have to convert your text file newlines to HTML linebreaks, using the [`linebreaksbr` Django template filter](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr), as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1356830/1211429).

Your code should look like:

```
{% autoescape on %}
    {{ contact.info | linebreaksbr }}
{% endautoescape %}
```

Comment: @user2092913 now it should ;)

Comment: Isn't allowing html tag, is printing the <br>

Comment: Oh, it works when I try to print direct in html, but Im using popover from bootstrap, the placeholder may do something:

data-content="{{contact.info| linebreaksbr}}"

Comment: Should work since you're escaping the html using `autoesacpe on`

Comment: What if you're not rendering it? I want to put `\n` characters in a `value` of an input field. Is there a way to preserve the `\n` characters with django template language?

Answer (score 6):

You want the [`linebreaks`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) filter:

```
{{contact.info | linebreaks}}
```

That being said, it would be better if `contact.info` was a list - then you could do:

```
{% for info in contact.info %}
{{ info }}<br />
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: Beat you by 4 seconds, but you provided the link, so have a +1. :)

Comment: @Wooble - *chuckles* and you deleted your post so I can't +1 you for beating me.

Comment: Isn't allowing html tag, is printing the <br>

Comment: @user2092913 - you may need to include a [`| safe`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.5/ref/templates/builtins/#std:templatefilter-safe) after the `linebreaks` filter (which would be a bug, to my mind, with the version of Django you are using).

Comment: How I said in another answer, Im using popover from bootstrap. When it is direct in html its works, but when I put it in placeholder it do not allow html tags...