# Django: show newlines from admin site?

Tags: python, html, django, newline, textfield

This is probably very simple. My database objects have a TextField. Now, when I add the contents of the TextFields to an html paragraph, there are no new lines. How can I make Django show those newlines? Thank you!

Comment: possible duplicate of [Django doesn't display newline character when rendering text from database](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356048/django-doesnt-display-newline-character-when-rendering-text-from-database)

Comment: Wait, there seems to be a problem...

Comment: Never mind, minor detail...

Comment: Could you select an answer if @Daniel Roseman has solved your problem?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the [`linebreaks`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks) template filter.

Comment: That seems to do the trick, but suddenly, my text has lost all it's properties. Color, size etc. Weird...