# wrap strings in html tags python

Tags: python, html, django, python-3.x

What's the easiest way to control taking strings to html, where you can feed attributes easily like the `id`, classes, etc, such that in one line you can pass a string:

```
'just install in crontab:\n    \n    crontab -e\n    \n    * * * * * /usr/bin/python ~/path/update_files.py'
```

and get

```
<p>just install in crontab:</p><p> </p><p> crontab -e</p><p> </p><p> * * * * * /usr/bin/python ~/path/update_files.py</p>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[You can use Django](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1356830/3896300) filters to convert your plain text newlines into HTML. linebreaks turns single newlines into `<br>` tags, and double newlines into `<p>` tags. linebreaksbr just turns newlines into `<br>` tags:

```
{{value|linebreaks}}
{{value|linebreaksbr}}
```

Comment: I want to control the html w python, like maybe make each like `<p class='orange'>` or `<button value={{ python_attr }}>`. your answer works for one use case but not most