# Django Form Field for Copying and Pasting Vertical List

Tags: python, django, forms

I am in the process of updating a project so that, in one of the apps, the user can copy a vertical list of values from a text/excel file/[file format] into a form. I want the form to hold as many values as the user will paste (so hopefully it will be dynamic in length).

When the user submits the form, my views.py will process the data. What field type should I use to do this? (If it is even possible to do this)

Comment: If you are not going to limit the amount of data the user can input you can just use a TextField. I would also recommend sanitizing the text prior to storing it in your DB.

Comment: Is there any way for the TextField to copy the vertical formatting (for instance, with a scroll bar)?

Comment: If there are line breaks, "\n", in the pasted data, they will remain when stored. When you go to render the stored data just wrap it in a <pre></pre> or use Django filters as explained in this post https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356048/django-doesnt-display-newline-character-when-rendering-text-from-database

Comment: Hmm I was more asking for visual purposes (I want the user to see the vertical box since it would be easier for them to modify whatever they copied/pasted). I think a vertical text field would look better. I won't have an issue processing the data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out! I just used a Textarea instead of a TextField.