# html5 - can't format `\n` as new line in rendered string

Tags: html, angularjs

I have the following tag but '\n' inside `item.value` not formatted correctly .

```
<td ng-if="flag">{{item.value}}</td>
```

Comment: Are you using django? May be consider https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356048/django-doesnt-display-newline-character-when-rendering-text-from-database

Comment: @eman.lodovice am not using it

Comment: @anwarmohamed Just to be sure, you are using AngularJS, right?

Comment: @Ivar yes I use it

Comment: @Quentin I am not think the same issue which mention above

Comment: @anwarmohamed In that case I think your question should be a duplicate of this question instead: [Preserve line breaks in angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19684708/preserve-line-breaks-in-angularjs)

Comment: thanks @Ivar , it is same

Answer (score 0):

HTML needs a `<br/>` tag. Use this regex on your value.

`item.value = item.value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');`

```js
let item = {};
item.value= "Hi I am some text with a \n line break";
item.value = item.value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');

document.write(item.value);
```

Comment: it shown as **item2 <br> item 1**

Comment: How are you writing it to your document?

Comment: `<td ng-if="flag"><pre style="color:black;white-space:normal !important;">{{ctrl.formatLine(item.value)}}</pre></td>`   ctrl--->  `self.formatLine = function (value) {
            return value.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, '<br>');
        };`

Comment: It seems like you have to use the [innerHTML] attribute/property binding, as answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49013217/how-to-render-string-with-html-tags-in-angular-4)

Comment: @abadr did it work?