# Different lines does not appear in context in Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-views

If I have code like

```
hello_worlds = 'hello Earth \n hello Mars'

context = {
          'hellos':hello_worlds
          }

return render(request, 'home.html', context)
```

and home.html is

```
{{hellos}}
```

It displays as

```
hello Earth hello Mars
```

not

```
hello Earth
hello Mars
```

I'm using Django 2.1.5 and python 3.8
is there a way to have it display like the second one?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356048/django-doesnt-display-newline-character-when-rendering-text-from-database

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of the [**`|linebreaks`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaks):

```
{{ hellos|linebreaks }}
```

This will transform the `hellos` to:

```
>>> Template('{{ hellos|linebreaks }}').render(Context(context))
'<p>hello Earth <br> hello Mars</p>'
```

or you can make use of the [**`|linebreaksbr`** template filter [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/templates/builtins/#linebreaksbr) to only add `<br>`s without the paragraphs `<p>`:

```
>>> Template('{{ hellos|linebreaksbr }}').render(Context(context))
'hello Earth <br> hello Mars'
```

Answer (score 1):

use the filter by pip(data|type) :
linebreaks the same with br at html

in your case : {{ hellos|linebreaks }}

Answer (score 1):

I think the first two guys have answered already.

You wouldn't need to break the lines in your views since you can do that in your template using the "linebreaks" template filter just like they've said :

{{hellos|linebreaks}}

Or,

{{hellos|linebreaksbr}}